# import error in python user interface, thony and pycharm

Tags: import

while importing tensor flow as import tensorflow it raise an error,:

import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 41, in 
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as *module_util
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python_*init**.py", line 40, in 
from tensorflow.python.eager import context
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in 
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in 
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Amit Maurya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue but I'm not sure if the solution is applicable here, too. Anyway, I'd suggest to install the MS Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 if you haven't done it yet.

You can find the redistributable [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).